# large number converted to scientific format by default in csv using jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm working with jasper reports and in one of the reports a column is getting converted into scientific format by default when I generate the report as csv format.

Below is the snippet of the column from my jrxml:

```
    <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="123" height="10" uuid="2eea8416-88ce-459a-a728-8c448690ba62"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
            <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cardNum}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

Below is the code snippet from my java class file, I made the changes based on the solutions I found on the web:

```
@Override
protected void prepareReportParameters(List recordList, String language) {
    //------get parameters form user input-------------------
    try {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("jasperproperties/dealertransactionreport/DealerTransactionReport", locale);
        reportParameters.put("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE", rb);
        reportParameters.put("jasperPath", path);
        reportParameters.put("recordCount", recordList.size());
        reportParameters.put("startDate", formatDate.parse(getParam("jrs.param$p_startDate")));
    reportParameters.put("endDate", formatDate.parse(getParam("jrs.param$p_endDate")));
        reportParameters.put("displaytcktNum", false);
        reportParameters.put("printDate", new Date());
        reportParameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
        reportParameters.put( JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,Boolean.FALSE);
        reportParameters.put( JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,Boolean.FALSE );
        doExportBandsValue();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ERROR:" + e, e);
    }
}
```

As seen above, I have added the `"JRXlsExporterParameter"` & `"JExcelApiExporterParameter"` properties and set them as false to fix the issue but I'm still seeing the scientific notation instead of the complete number. How can I fix this issue?.

Below is what I'm seeing when I generate a report:

[image]

Comment: What data type is `cardNum`? Also, consider posting a complete, minimal, working example.

Comment: Its a string, <field name="cardNum" class="java.lang.String"/>

Comment: Where is the value for `cardNum` being assigned? Show as much code as you can. Strings are displayed verbatim, so the value in the spreadsheet will equal whatever value `cardNum` receives in the Java code -- not in the report template.

Comment: The pattern used by excel is  what you are setting in `<textField pattern=""....`, hence no pattern, try to set the pattern you like, as it is this question can not be answered until we see complete jrxml relative to the `$F{cardNum}`, class declaration ecc.