# Jasper Report exports numbers with scientific notation in CSV

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper Report that uses a bean collection as datasource.
I have a Java application that uses this Jasper Report to export some data to CSV File.
The problem is that when exported, some columns defined as BigInteger in the bean collection are shown with scientific notation and I'm out of options of how to show them with normal notation.

I investigated over Internet, including the following links:

- [JasperReports: How to format numeric data with Excel exporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714709/jasperreports-how-to-format-numeric-data-with-excel-exporter)
- [Export to Excel format: cell type "general" and number turn into scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214123/export-to-excel-format-cell-type-general-and-number-turn-into-scientific-nota)
- [large number converted to scientific format by default in csv using jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504443/large-number-converted-to-scientific-format-by-default-in-csv-using-jasper-repor)
- https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/excel-export-number-stored-text

And I followed these steps without avail:

1. Set the parameter `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type` to true
2. Use the class `java.text.DecimalFormat` and set the format to "0"
3. Convert (without casting) the `BigInteger` field to `BigDecimal` and use the `BigDecimal.toPlainString()` method
4. Set the text field value to `="$F{myObject}"`
5. Changed the field type to a proper Java Class (`BigInteger`, `Long`,etc.)

The textfields using those fields are defined as follows:

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="2109" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="462b3e91-55ec-4250-b90b-e524afd3bb8d"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{stSimcard}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

And almost all of those fields are declared in the report as `String`, although some are declared as `java.math.BigInteger`:

`<field name="stSimcard" class="java.lang.String"/>`

For each one of the steps mentioned above:

1. Set the parameter `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type` to true

Expected value: The created CSV file shall display the value in normal notation, i.e., "8956030165644580" when opened with Microsoft Excel

Actual value: The value is displayed in scientific notation, i.e., 8,956E+15 in the cell, but ih shows the complete number in the formula's text field and it forces me to change the cell format in order to show the number correctly

2. Use the class `java.text.DecimalFormat` and set the format to "0":

`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.DecimalFormat("0").format($F{stSimcard})]]></textFieldExpression>`

The expected and actual output are the same as the first step.

3. Convert (without casting) the `BigInteger` field to `BigDecimal` and use the `BigDecimal.toPlainString()` method

`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.math.BigDecimal($F{stSimcard}.longValue()).toPlainString()]]></textFieldExpression>`

The expected and actual output are the same as the first step.

4. Set the text field value to `="$F{myObject}"`

`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["=\"" + $F{stSimcard} + "\""]]></textFieldExpression>`

Expected output: Same as the first step

Actual output: The CSV file displays ='' without the field value in it.

5. Changed the field type to a proper Java Class (`BigInteger`, `Long`,etc.)

   The expected and actual output are the same as the first step.

Some aditional info:

- I don't want to use something like this, because I must not display something besides the field values:

`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["'" + $F{stSimcard}]]></textFieldExpression>`

- I will understand if some of you says that the only solution is to change the cell format in Excel.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The datasource for the report is defined as follows:

```
Collection<VentasMovil> elementos = new ArrayList<VentasMovil>();

//Filling collection from another collection obtained from database through a Hibernate repository interface

JRDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(elementos);
```

Comment: "I have a Jasper Report that uses a bean collection as datasource". This might be a problem. It is often easier to just send ready-to-use values to Jasper. This is also easier to unit test.

Comment: You mean use a SQL Select or a XML as datasource?

Comment: No, I mean : instead of sending raw beans to Jasper, you could do the heavy job on Java side then send beans with already formatted data to Jasper. Then Jasper would just have to display the received beans with very few business logic.

Comment: I edited the post adding the way the datasource is defined. When you say "raw beans", do you mean beans defined as above?

Answer (score 0):

net.sf.jasperreports.export.**xls**.detect.cell.type - this property is applicable only for XLS/XLSX export as these formats keep rich data formatting.

[CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is pretty simple format. Try to open CSV in Notepad: if it's ok then issue lies on MS-Excel side. Also Excel has [limitation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) of number precision = 15 digits.

It is possible to import CSV to Excel via *Data* tab -> *From Text* and then set column separator, text format for big numbers, etc.

Comment: You are right. I opened the CSV file with a Text Editor (in my case is Notepad++) and the numbers are shown correctly. That means the problem is not from Jasper but from MS Excel, so there is nothing I can do here. Thanks a lot.